# temp->next = ptr; temp->next->prev = ptr; please tell me what is this code saying in double link list insertion of node after a specified location?

Tags: java, c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

**Here is the code**

This is a function which is inserting a node after a specified location. Here we have temp and ptr node. Temp node will store the node after which new node is need to be inserted and ptr node is storing the data of new node.

here after locating the temp node, this is assigning the pointer details of temp and next node.

Here **temp node next pointer** store the new node **ptr**

and **ptr previous pointer** store the address of **temp** node

and **ptr next pointer** store the address of **temp node's next pointer**

but here this line what is saying i didn't understand **temp->next->prev = ptr;**

```
void randomInsert()
{
    struct node *ptr, *temp;
    int item, loc, i;
    ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "overflow" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        cout << "Enter the location" << endl;
        cin >> loc;
        for (i = 1; i < loc; i++)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                cout << "There are less then " << loc << " elements" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        cout << "Enter value" << endl;
        cin >> item;
        ptr->data = item;
        ptr->next = temp->next;
        ptr->prev = temp;
        temp->next = ptr;
        temp->next->prev = ptr;
        cout << "Node Inserted" << endl;
    }
}
```

Link of complete code https://www.javatpoint.com/doubly-linked-list

Answer (score 0):

That code is wrong.

```
    temp->next = ptr;
    temp->next->prev = ptr;
```

After `temp->next = ptr;` the line that follows is equivalent to:

```
    ptr->prev = ptr;
```

...which makes it a self-reference.

Either the assignments should be swapped, to this:

```
    temp->next->prev = ptr;
    temp->next = ptr;
```

Or, the `ptr` should be used in the longer assignment:

```
    temp->next = ptr;
    ptr->next->prev = ptr;
```

### Visualisation

To understand this, it helps to visualise it.

After the loop has ended, `temp` will reference the node *after* which the new node (referenced by `ptr`) should be inserted.

So just before that happens, we have a situation that can be visualised like this:

```
        ptr
         ↓
       ┌───────────┐
       │ value: 3  │
       │ next: null│
       │ prev: null│
       └───────────┘

 
        temp
         ↓
       ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    
       │ value: 2  │    │ value: 4  │    
       │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> ...
... <─────── :prev │ <─────── :prev │
       └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

When we apply the following two statements:

```
ptr->next = temp->next; 
ptr->prev = temp;
```

... we get this:

```
                           ptr
                            ↓
                          ┌───────────┐
                          │ value: 3  │
                          │ next: ────────┐
                      ┌──────── :prev │   │ 
                      │   └───────────┘   │
        temp          │                   │
         ↓            │                   │
       ┌───────────┐  │                   │  ┌───────────┐    
       │ value: 2  │ <┘                   └> │ value: 4  │    
       │ next: ────────────────────────────> │ next: ───────> ...
... <─────── :prev │ <──────────────────────────── :prev │
       └───────────┘                         └───────────┘
```

Then with `temp->next = ptr;` we get:

```
                           ptr
                            ↓
                          ┌───────────┐
                          │ value: 3  │
                          │ next: ────────┐
                      ┌──────── :prev │   │ 
                      │┌> └───────────┘   │
        temp          ││                  │
         ↓            ││                  │
       ┌───────────┐  ││                  │  ┌───────────┐    
       │ value: 2  │ <┘│                  └> │ value: 4  │    
       │ next: ────────┘                     │ next: ───────> ...
... <─────── :prev │ <──────────────────────────── :prev │
       └───────────┘                         └───────────┘
```

So there is one update missing. It would be wrong now to do `temp->next-prev = ptr;`. The correct assignment is `ptr->next->prev = ptr;`, which leads to the final state:

```
                           ptr
                            ↓
                          ┌───────────┐
                          │ value: 3  │
                          │ next: ────────┐
                      ┌──────── :prev │ <┐│ 
                      │┌> └───────────┘  ││
        temp          ││                 ││
         ↓            ││                 ││
       ┌───────────┐  ││                 ││  ┌───────────┐    
       │ value: 2  │ <┘│                 │└> │ value: 4  │    
       │ next: ────────┘                 │   │ next: ───────> ...
... <─────── :prev │                     └──────── :prev │
       └───────────┘                         └───────────┘
```